# Why does my VBA code throw an "Invalid outside procedure" error?

Tags: vba, excel

For the life of me I cannot figure out why the following code is throwing a compile error with the message "Invalid outside procedure". It is highlighting the error on the starred line below.

```
Option Explicit

Dim shtThisSheet As Worksheets

**Set shtThisSheet = Application.Workbook("Formatting2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")**

Sub Formatting()

    With shtThisSheet

        With Range("A1")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 14
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End With

        With Range("A3:A6")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Italic = True
            .Font.ColorIndex = 5
            .InsertIndent 1
        End With

        With Range("B2:D2")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Italic = True
            .Font.ColorIndex = 5
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End With

        With Range("B3:D6")
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: also you are trying to dim to a collection (Worksheets) instead of an object (Worksheet)

Comment: Also you are using `with shtThisSheet` but then not referencing that in your `Range` statements. you should be using `.Range` instead.

Answer (score 13):

`Set` statements aren't allowed outside procedures. Move the `Set` statement into the `Formatting` procedure:

```
Sub Formatting()
    Set shtThisSheet = Application.Workbook("Formatting2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ...
```

(I'd move the `Dim` statement into the procedure as well. I prefer to avoid global variables when possible.)

Comment: This fixed the old issue (thank you), Do yo know why it may cause a script out of range error?

Comment: Set shtThisSheet = Application.Workbooks("Formatting2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: It probably can't find an open workbook named Formatting2.xlsm, or it can't find a sheet named Sheet1 in that workbook.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare variables as global, but you cannot set them outside of a procedure such as a sub or function.

If you need this variable as a global, then it's best to set it on.
    Workbook_Open()

If you do not need it as a global, then move both the declaration and the set statement into your procedure