# run time error 445 object doesn't support this action

Tags: excel, vba

Got this error **run time error 445 object doesn't support this action** while trying to launch thise code . Macros works, but everytime i run it gives me this error, can i somehow get rid of it?

```
    Sub Toggle_Row_Field()
'Add/Remove the field to the pivot table.
'The field is determined by the button text that calls the macro.

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sField As String
Dim shp As Shape

  'Set variables
  Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
  Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
  sField = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
  
  'Toggle field
  'If visible then hide it
  If pt.PivotFields(sField).Orientation = xlRowField Then
    pt.PivotFields(sField).Orientation = xlHidden
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.5
  Else 'Add to Rows area
    pt.PivotFields(sField).Orientation = xlRowField
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
  End If

End Sub
```

**Update**

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are declaring an `OLEobject` as `shape`, as OLEobjectdoes not has the property of `Fill.Forecolor` as following:

[image]

In order to use the property of `Fill.Forecolor` you should draw a shape and assign the VBA code to the shape, the red one is `Shape` while the grey one is `OLEobject`

[image]

So the moment I click the `shape`, it will change color and also remove the `pivot field` as per your expectation:

[image]

**Part 2: DataFiled:**
It is quite trick to make `value field` hide or display, however you still can use the following method to solve it.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sField As String, SFieldSum As String
Dim shp As Shape
Dim blfound As Boolean

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
sField = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
SFieldSum = "Sum of " & shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text

For Each pf In pt.DataFields
    If pf.Name = SFieldSum Then
      blfound = True
      Exit For
    End If
Next
  
If blfound Then
   pt.PivotFields(SFieldSum).Orientation = xlHidden
  shp.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.5
Else
  pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields(sField), SFieldSum, xlSum
  shp.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! Can i somehow change it in the code to be just shape instead of color?

Comment: thank you very much! Can i somehow change it in the code to be just shape instead of color?  @KInSiang

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `ActiveX control` instead of `shape`?

Comment: Check my part2 answer, it is working now for `value field` also, accept the answer if helping :)

Comment: it says compile error, while trying to run it. Can you please look at the screen i posted on question? thank you!!

Comment: Did you assign the code to a shape and you value is `Sum of xx`? Let me update in image also

Comment: oh , its a  calculated field. Will be the same thing?

Comment: i think you only show part of your code, and this is your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319309/why-does-my-vba-code-throw-an-invalid-outside-procedure-error

Comment: Welcome, glad it help you :)